# How do I Set-up and Tear-down variables (and driver) around my JUnit tests?

Tags: java, mongodb, selenium, testing, junit

I'd like to run two similar Junit/Selenium tests of this form:

```
@Test
public void findMyLinkTest() {
        running(testServer(1234, fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase())), HTMLUNIT, browser -> {
            browser.goTo("http://localhost:1234");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("http://localhost:1234");
            List<WebElement> myLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("blahblahblah"));
            assertTrue(myLinks.size()==1);
            driver.close();
        });
}
```

But **@Before** I'd like to

- change database variables (that feed into my application) to a test value
- set up `driver` for both tests

and **@After**

- re**set** the database variables
- initiate `driver.close()`

My Before and After methods don't seem to recognise variables in other blocks (**@After** thinks driver was never instantiated for example).

Comment: Please post the code with the _variables in other blocks_. As **@Before** and **@After** methods are typical non-static methods they have the same access to variables as the junit test methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good way to do this is to create  a separate class which does setup and teardown and make sure other test class extends this one.

Following code might help you understand what I am saying. 
your base test class should look like this.

```
   public abstract class BaseTest {

        protected WebDriver driver;
        protect Database dbCon;
        @Before
        public void setup(){
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            //initialize teh connection same way

        }

        @After
        public void tearDown(){
            driver.close();
            dbCon.close() ;
        }
    }
```

Your other test class(s)

```
public class MyTest extends BaseTest{

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        //here you will have access to both
    }
}
```

Comment: This turned out to be simpler than I expected so I solved the problem before seeing your answer, but your suggestion to modularise the set-up was excellent.

As in your answer, the problem was that all variables needed to be instantiated outside any '@Before', '@After', '@Test'; before setting or manipulating them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) qnd [@AfterClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html) for one time initialization/teardown of the resources used by the test set contained in the class

Answer (score 0):

Use `@BeforeClass`/`@AfterClass` for the common setup/teardown for all tests in a class. In this [repository](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples) you can find working examples of JUnit + WebDriver (e.g. using [Chrome](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/ChromeTest.java), [Firefox](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/FirefoxTest.java), etc).